# SQL Query, get only the line where a value appear 4 time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a table `Customer (ID, Ref, LastName, FirstName)`.

I have to bring out all lines whose reference is the same at least four times.

I tried this unsuccessfully :

```
SELECT * from MyTable Where (select count(ref) from MyTable Group By ref) >= 4
```

Of course it is wrong, but I don't know how to do this in one query.

Comment: `select * from table group by ID,LN,FN having count(Ref)>=4`

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi - And if there are 4 rows but all with a different value in the `ref` field?

Comment: @Chris - What platform?  SQL Server 2012, for example?  Different platforms have different options for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` clause like below

```
SELECT * from Customer 
Where ref in (select ref from Customer Group By ref having count(*) >= 4)
```

**[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/405b3/1)**

Comment: Looking good @Upendra Chaudhari, thought it was possible without the Select in the select, but this does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use the [`Having`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause in the query:

```
SELECT Ref, LastName, FirstName 
from MyTable
group by Ref, LastName, FirstName 
having count(*) >= 4
```

I have omitted `ID`, since this is possibly a primary key and probably not required here as the grouping wouldn't work.

**EDIT**: Since the above query will not return your result...You can also use a join...

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Customer c
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT ref
                     FROM   Customer
                     GROUP BY ref
                     HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
                   ) t ON c.ref = t.ref
```

Comment: That is correct christian, check this resource: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: If multiple customers have same ref then it will not come in your query cause you are grouping by first name and last name also

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari, since the information is limited, I have assumed the query.  The main point is that the OP needs to use the `Having` clause.

Comment: @christiandev, thanks for the advice. I am a stackoverflow kinda guy anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from MyTable Group By ref HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4`

Comment: You are going to have to use the HAVING for sure

Comment: Check the answer by @Upendra also

Comment: No... you are select * and grouping on only ref... This will work if the table has only one column Ref

Comment: I changed the count(ref) to count(*), that should do the trick

Comment: @Theo - You *can not* select a column that you are not grouping by.  As written you'd need `SELECT ref` in place of `SELECT *`

Comment: Please try running the same query on any of your table. you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Ref, LastName, FirstName 
from YourTable
group by Ref, LastName, FirstName 
having count(*) >= 4`

Answer (score 0):

assuming records with the same Reference associate to the same customer then something meaningful can be got from :

```
select ID , max(Ref) as the_Ref , count(Ref) as count_ref  from Customer group by Ref having count(Ref) >= 4;
```

If , however ,  Ref refers to something which occurs independently of the existence of customers ( maybe its used to refer to customer orders ) I'd recommend you consider normalising (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data model a little more into two tables instead of one viz :

```
Customer( ID , firstName , LastName ) 
Customer_Order ( Ref , Customer_ID)
```

whats known as a foreign key relationship can then be set up between these two tables

Answer (score 0):

As a lover of INNER JOIN, I would prefer the following way.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Ref, LastName, FirstName, COUNT(1) AS NumberOfRef
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY Ref, LastName, FirstName
) T ON T.Ref = C.Ref AND T.LastName = C.LastName AND T.FirstName = C.FirstName AND T.NumberOfRef >= 4
```

However, after I did it, I started to feel the table Customer to be a bit strange. Even though we normalize it, as @diarmuid suggested, what should we use as the primary key for Customer_Order?

```
Customer(ID , FirstName, LastName ) 
Customer_Order (Ref, CustomerID)
```